# Read PowerPoint into R

Tags: r, reporters

Is it possible to import PowerPoint files into R? 
I saw that you can use the ReporteRs package to create and manipulate powerpoint files, but I couldnt find anything on importing them.

I was hoping that I could load a pptx into an object like.

```
pptx1<-read.ppt(file1)
pptx2<-read.ppt(file2)
```

and then merge them into one file

```
pptx1<-addslide(pptx2,..)
```

Background: I would like to create a reporting tool based on slides from many different powerpoint files and since I am very bad at VBA, I was hoping that R could be a good alternative.

Answer (score 4):

maybe too late but package `officer` can import data from pptx or docx file in a tidy format:

```
example_pptx <- system.file(package = "officer", "doc_examples/example.pptx")
doc <- read_pptx(example_pptx)
content <- pptx_summary(doc)
content

# A tibble: 29 x 9
                text    id content_type slide_id row_id cell_id col_span
               <chr> <chr>        <chr>    <int>  <int>   <int>    <dbl>
 1             Title    12    paragraph        1     NA      NA       NA
 2          A table     13    paragraph        1     NA      NA       NA
 3     and some text    13    paragraph        1     NA      NA       NA
 4 and some list (1)    13    paragraph        1     NA      NA       NA
 5 and some list (2)    13    paragraph        1     NA      NA       NA
 6         Header 1     18   table cell        1      1       1        1
 7          Header 2    18   table cell        1      1       2        1
 8          Header 3    18   table cell        1      1       3        1
 9                 A    18   table cell        1      2       1        1
10             12.23    18   table cell        1      2       2        1
# ... with 19 more rows, and 2 more variables: row_span <dbl>,
#   media_file <chr>
```

Comment: Cool, can you edit the slides within R afterwards or just merge two different slides into one file and also write it as a new pptx? Then this would be my answer, even though I do not need it anymore :) @David Gohel

Comment: yes, you can modify slides, I am not sure what you mean by "merge two different slides into one file".

Comment: OK, I was blind because of the title of your question... No, this can't be done.

Comment: Ah thats a pity, but this would be a nice thing to have. A function that allows you to copy an entire slide from your your example and paste it into an empty object created from read_pptx()
By the way the pptx_summary function did not work for me. I dowloaded your package from CRAN

Comment: what didn't work? you got an error, you got an empty table?

Comment: Error: could not find function "pptx_summary"
I could also not download the system.file example, but this is probably due to something else

Comment: In stead of `.pptx`, if my template is `.ppt` format, how could I read it?