# R read powerpoint .ppt file

Tags: r, powerpoint

I am looking for a solution how to read .ppt files (the old type, NOT .pptx) using R. I know the thread as stated here [Read PowerPoint into R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39162473/read-powerpoint-into-r) but I am, as I said, interested in .ppt files.
I could not find any package that is able to do this.

Does anyone know a solution for this? I basically  just need the text in the .ppt file.

Thanks!

Comment: Try `slidex`: https://github.com/datalorax/slidex

Comment: They are saying the following: "Support both .ppt and .pptx file types. Currently only the latter is supported. Will require LibreOffice." unfortunately i cannot wait that long. any other solutions?

Comment: Perhaps take this to [SoftwareRecs](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), a site designed for recommendations such as this.

Comment: i took it to SoftwareRecs: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/52849/read-powerpoint-ppt-file There is a solution for everyone who is interested.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the tables in pptx or texts, you can try eoffice

```
install.packages(eoffice)
library(eoffice)
totable(t.test(wt ~ am, mtcars), filename = file.path(tempdir(), "mtcars.pptx"))
tabs <- inpptx(filename = file.path(tempdir(), "mtcars.pptx"), header = TRUE)
tabs
```